# outOfMemory Exception while re-encoding image

Tags: java, android, filestream

I'm trying to encode an image to 64 base ,

after choosing the image from gallery and trying to save it I am getting this error:

outOfMemory Exception

can any one suggest how to to get this image to base 64 without memory error?

```
        MotorImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}


 @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();


 //   
   ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));



    String imageString = null;

    try {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object  
        bm.recycle();
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        imageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), imageString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Do not write to `ByteArrayOutputStream`, write to a file, network socket, ... you can't write arbitrarily large data into memory. Also don't encode to `String` because that's writing into memory as well. There are outputstreams for that as well.

Comment: i want to save it as string cuz i will store it in sql server database , what should i use ?

Comment: You don't need a `String`, you can stream it to your server as well. How depends on your server and many other factors.

Comment: base64-ing an image is really not a good idea and should be avoided.

Comment: @njzk2 do you have another ideas ?

Comment: use Base64OutputStream on a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you need to scale and resample your image to fit within the constraints on the device, try something like this

```
// decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeImage(String picturePath) {
    try {
        File file = new File(picturePath);
        // Get image size
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, opts);

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int MIN_SIZE = 70;

        // Find the correct scale value.
        int scale = 1;
        while (((opts.outWidth / scale) >> 1) >= MIN_SIZE
                && ((opts.outHeight / scale) >> 1) >= MIN_SIZE) {
            scale <<= 1;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options opts2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, opts2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: can you edit this with taking string of image path instead of File

Comment: @user3245658 Sorry. I missed that. It's `opts`. Edited.

Comment: @user3245658 I know. But first you must decode it and scale it, then encode it! :)

Comment: so I should use my original post here after your method ?

Comment: @user3245658 After you scale the image your original method should work; I would suggest you try a streaming solution (instead of an in memory one) for saving; but this should reduce the size of the output enough for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `android:largeHeap="true"` inside the application tag on AndroidManifest, then your app will have more ram available and will not throw a oom exception.

Comment: what is your android version?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the official document of android you will come to know that this is a common issue with android and the recommended solution is to resize image according to your need. you can refer developer.android for this as well